# Product-Detail-Component showing broken page with no CSS (Laravel 9)

Tags: php, css, mysql, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have used -

`Route::get("/product-detail/{slug}",App\Http\Livewire\ProductDetailComponent::class)->name("product-detail");`

in the web routes.

Furthermore, I am using -
`{{route('product-detail',['slug'=>$product->slug])}}`
in my shop-component.blade.php, to access a product page.

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Product;
class ProductDetailComponent extends Component
{
    public $p_slug;
    public function mount($slug)
    {
        $this->p_slug=$slug;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        $product=Product::where('slug',$this->p_slug)->first();
        return view('livewire.product-detail-component',['product'=>$product])->layout("layouts.base");
    }
}

this is what I have used in my ProductDetailComponent.php file
```

Comment: Can you add a question or say what you are seeing versus what you are expecting to see? Also, try using code formatting around your quoted code to help differentiate it, as it is hard to read as regular text.

Comment: Hey Eric, thanks for pointing it out. I am still figuring out how the stack works, as I am new here. To clarify, I wish to see a product detail page for each product, however, all I am seeing is a broken page with no CSS. The page content is still there though. I think there is some problem in the route.

Comment: Yes, generally you need a regular blade file to provide the overall layout and then the livewire component is placed on that page like `<livewire:product-detail :slug="$slug">`. Do you have other pages that are showing content as expected?

Comment: Yes, all other pages are good to go! Just this one is broken. Can't seem to figure it out. :(

Comment: I assume you've set it up properly then? Like [so](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#page-components)? Since you have more than one page loading correctly? Are you using a correct slot name?

Comment: Hey everyone, I figured it out. The path for my CSS and JS files was incomplete in the base.blade.php file. I added 'asset' to each one of them and voila! Everything seems to be working fine now. Thanks for all your help.